# i am trying to create CRUD application using Spring + spring data JPA + Bootstrap but i am getting this error

Tags: hibernate, jpa

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ BootSample ---

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2018-06-07 09:09:32.344  INFO 10208 --- [           main] com.mycompany.bootsample.Application     : Starting Application on LPTADO76 with PID 10208 (started by s2026045 in D:\New folder\java\projects\BootSample)
2018-06-07 09:09:32.344  INFO 10208 --- [           main] com.mycompany.bootsample.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-07 09:09:32.484  INFO 10208 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@125dc0f: startup date [Thu Jun 07 09:09:32 GMT+02:00 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-07 09:09:35.773  INFO 10208 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef6327ab] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-07 09:09:37.393  INFO 10208 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-06-07 09:09:37.433  INFO 10208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2018-06-07 09:09:37.453  INFO 10208 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2018-06-07 09:09:37.793  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-06-07 09:09:37.793  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5329 ms
2018-06-07 09:09:38.093  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-06-07 09:09:38.103  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-07 09:09:38.103  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-07 09:09:38.103  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-07 09:09:38.103  INFO 10208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-07 09:09:38.233  WARN 10208 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2018-06-07 09:09:38.233  INFO 10208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2018-06-07 09:09:38.463  INFO 10208 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-07 09:09:38.463 ERROR 10208 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

---

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 12.621s
Finished at: Thu Jun 07 09:09:38 GMT+02:00 2018

### Final Memory: 9M/247M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project BootSample: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>BootSample</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>BootSample</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--sqlserver Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

here is my application.properties file

```html
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:8080;databaseName=User
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = P@ssw0rd
spring.datasource.driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = debug

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Comment: share your pom.xml and application.properties

Comment: Hi Yogesh Prajapati, i've shared mypom.xml and application.properties

Answer (score 0):

As you have added jpa/data starter in your pom.xml you should provide any datasource configuration.

Boot will complain if configuration is missing.
Example: http://www.kode12.com/kode12/spring-boot/spring-boot-database-connectivity-mysql-web/

Comment: Hi Yogesh Prajapati, i did create application.properties. let me update the question with pom and my application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot provides some autoconfigurations for in-memory databases such like H2, HSQL and Derby. Just add a build dependencies of one of them to your pom and Spring Boot will do the configuration for you if you want a fast way to get up and running.

E.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.197</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

More information can be found under:

[Embedded Database Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-database-support)

Comment: hi Weber, i am using sqlserver